# %run Python function in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to run a function from IPython and load all of its data into the interactive namespace, just like how `%run filename.py` does it.  E.g., here's the file `scratch.py`:

```
def foo(x):
    a = x*2
```

In IPython, I'd like to run this function and be able to access the name `a`.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the variable available globally (or in some interactive IPython session), you first have to define it as global:

```
def foo(x):
    global a
    a = x*2
```

Otherwise your `a` remains a local variable within your function. More infos e.g. here: [Use of “global” keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693385/4077977)

Comment: How can I call `foo` from IPython to access `a`, then?  I've tried `from scratch import foo` then `foo(2)`, but I still get a NameError when I then type `a` saying it is not defined.

Comment: Add `return a` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a `ipython` or `%run` issue, but rather a question of what you can do with variables created with a function.  It applies to any function run in Python.

A function has a `local` namespace, where it puts the variables that you define in that function.  That is, by design, local to the function - it isn't supposed to 'bleed' into the calling namespare (global of the module or local of the calling function).  This is a major reason from using functions - to isolate it's variables from the calling one.

If you need to see the variables in a function you can do several things:

- use global (often a sign of poor design)
- use local prints (temporary, for debugging purposes)
- return the values  (normal usage)
- use a debugger.

This is a useless function:

```
def foo(x):
    a = x*2
```

this may have some value

```
def foo(x):
    a = x*2
    return a

def foo(x):
    a = x*2
    print(a)     # temporary debugging print
    # do more with a and x
    return ...
```

In a clean design, a function takes arguments, and returns values, with a minimum of side effects.  Setting global variables is a side effect that makes debugging your code harder.